# Length and width of photon - check logic

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, wavelength

so if $E = h\nu = \frac{h c}{\lambda} = pc$ where $\lambda$ is the photon's wavelength, $h$ is planck's constant, and $p$ is the photon's momentum

and

$L = \frac{p}{h}$ where L is length and p is the momentum of a photon

and

$p = \frac{h}{\lambda}$

rearranging we get $E = \frac{hc}{\lambda}$, but $p = \frac{h}{\lambda}$ and $L = \frac{p}{h}$. Substituting $L$ for $p$ and rearranging gives $L = \lambda$ i.e. the possible length of a photon is $\lambda$.

If $L = \lambda$ then $E = \frac{hc}{L}$, so $LE = hc$, with $hc$ constant, so length times energy of a photon is a constant, so as energy decreases length must increase, indicating that all photons carry the same amount of energy, just crammed in a bigger or smaller volume (energy density)?

Now if a photon is a sinusoidal electric and magnetic field  then the energy of a photon is the integral over zero to 2 pi of (Amp sin lambda) (for just the electric field say)  where Amp is the amplitude of the electric field

the integral will only be over one wavelength because the length of a photon is $L = \lambda =$ one wavelength

which gives

$A^2 = \frac{hc}{\lambda \varepsilon}$ for clarity (amplitude squared  = hC/Le) where $\varepsilon$ is the permittivity of free space.
So $h, c$ and $\varepsilon$ are all constants and the thickness (amplitude) of a photon is also a function of wavelength $\lambda$.

So, the thickness (width) of the photon is $2A$, where $A$ is the amplitude of the electric field, or the magnetic field. It is a trivial exercise to calculate the amplitude (thickness) of the B field

So, a photon has a length of $\lambda$ (one wavelength) and a thickness (width) of $2 \sqrt{\frac{hc}{L\varepsilon}}$

so the thickness of a photon is aso a function of $\lambda$

does that make sense ?

Comment: What is L=p/h physically? Dimensions are not correct if L is length and h is Planck's constant. p=h/L would be dimensionally consistent, but then, what is L? You later seem to  imply this is wavelength, but why did you begin with L=p/h ? What does "_possible length of a photon_" mean?

Comment: the units of momentum divided by the units of planks constant give a length in m

Comment: if you know the momentum of a photon and planks constant then you can calculate the length in m or a possible length inm of a photon, which turns out to be lambda, the wavelength

Comment: momentum of a photon p = h/lambda

Comment: $[p]$ are $kg ms^{-1}$ and $[h]=kg m^2s^{-1}$ so $[p]/[h]=L^{-1}$ and not [L]. Your whole argument fails if you think its [L].

Comment: "possible length of a photon" ...I said "possible" length bc of quantum effects , that will be the mean length in a population of billions of photons all of the same wavelength

Comment: so it will be the inverse  L = h/p si L = 1/Lambda ..Ill check for myself as I am taking from a university lecture

Comment: Yes, that is what I mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: Since $p = h/\lambda$ the quantity $p/h$ is $1/\lambda$. This is not a length but the inverse of a length. Please either correct your equation or use a word other than "length" for the quantity  $p/h$. You can all it "wavenumber" for example. (And by the way the length of the wavefunction for a photon is constrained by the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, so it is very long if the frequency is precise).

Comment: Your whole argument fails if you think its [L]. – 
lol, wot, no it doesn't it just means the length is a diff length to what I stated

Comment: Since p=h/λ the quantity p/h is 1/λ. This is not a length but the inverse of a length. Please either correct your equation or use a word other th.. yeah umm pretty sure the inverse of a length is still just a another length? taking the inverse of a unit does not change the unit

Comment: No! The inverse of a length is not a length. It could be wave number $k\propto 1/ \lambda$ but not a length. “_the inverse of a unit does not change a unit_” That is so incredibly wrong that I don’t even know how to answer it.

Comment: (And by the way the length of the wavefunction for a photon is constrained by the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, so it is very long if the frequency is precise)...but doesnt that simply say in a population of many photons the mean will be x and the upper limit will be the H constraint ? so in fact the very longest photon will be very long but the mean will be a function of the inverse of the momentum

Comment: so if L^-1 = h/p...then L = p/h ?? ie swap the h and the p

Comment: yeah right sorry the inverse of an inverse length, is a length

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! In this website, [we render equations using MathJax](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation), so they are more readable. Currently, it is a bit complicated to follow your calculations in the way they are written. Would you mind rewriting them using the tools described [in this link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation)?

Answer (score 2):

> rearranging we get $L = \lambda$

This is somewhat correct (though note that as pointed out in the comments, your way of arriving here is incorrect), the "length" of a single photon energy quantum is indeed just the wavelength. However, it is more sensible to just talk about the wavelength as this is a far more general concept that remains useful when talking about a beam of light containing many energy quanta. For example, a laster beam of length 1 meter long and consisting of 100 nm photons, does not necesarily contain $10^8$ photons in its length.

> It is a trivial exercise to calculate the amplitude (thickness) of the B field

It is indeed, and doing so would give us an immediate reason to be very suspicious of your results. You defined the width to be the twice the amplitude of the electric field, but do not provide a reason why to take the electric field and not the magnetic field. The amplitude of the magnetic field is $A_B = A_E/c^2$ which is significantly smaller. How would we explain that the thickness of the photon is simultaneously $2A_E$ and $2A_B = 2A_E/c^2$ which differ even in units!

> indicating that all photons carry the same amount of energy, just crammed in a bigger or smaller volume

No, this is not correct. $E$ is not the energy density, it is the total energy carried by the photon. $LE = hc$ gives $L^2 u = hc$, where $u$ is the energy per unit length. Integrating over length, we get $E = \int_0^L \frac{hc}{L^2}dL' = \frac{hc}{L}$ which is exactly the formula for the energy carried by a photon.

> so the thickness (width) of the photon is 2A, where A is the amplitude of the electric field, or the magnetic field

This too is not correct, $A$ is the amplitude of the oscilations in the electric field, they do not correspond to oscillations in any spatial dimensions. This is really about the strenght of the electric field at an infinitesimal point in space and has nothing to do with physical width.

Comment: jesus how do you cite on this platform ?

Comment: This is somewhat correct (though note that as pointed out in the comments, your way of arriving here is incorrect), the "length" of a single photon energy quantum is indeed just the wavelength. However, it is more sensible to just talk about the wavelength as this is a far more general concept that remains useful when talking about a beam of light containing many energy quanta. For example, a laster beam of length 1 meter long and consisting of 100 nm photons, does not necesarily contain 108 photons in its length....fine that is that settled

Comment: It is indeed, and doing so would give us an immediate reason to be very suspicious of your results. You defined the width to be the twice the amplitude of the electric field, but do not provide a reason why  ....... if I know the length ie one wavelength, then the amplitude (thickness of the photon) of the E and B fields can be calculated and from that an approx volume which would give energy density

Comment: so the length, despite my mistake, is one wavelength...thats means the rest of my calculations must be right ?

Comment: if you wanted to caclulcate the amplitude of the E field, for a photon of a given energy, (assuming a photon is sinusoidal) and a given length (lambda)  then you would integrate over the length A Sin x...where A is the unknown amplitude

Comment: @TomJones No, it does not mean the rest of your calculations are correct, as I have explained. The amplitude of the electric field is not the width of the photon and $LE$ fixed does not mean that the energy is the same for all photons, it means that the energy is inversely proporitonal to the wavelength.

Comment: well ok so what is the "width" of a photon then if the width is not defined by the max amplitude of the B and E field ?

Comment: you dont have a lot of parameters to play width

Comment: I don't believe a photon has a width. When approximated as a point particle, it is infinitesimal in all three dimensions, when approximated as a wave, it is infinitesimal in two out of three dimensions. Neither of the two have a width. But honestly, this should be a separate question. I just know enough about E&M to say that amplitude of electromagnetic oscilations are definitely not correspondent to spatial width.

Comment: diff units for B field, so are you saying the amplitude of the B field cannot be expressed as a distance ?

Comment: I don't believe a photon has a width. When approximated as a point particle, it is infinitesimal in all three dimensions,...so you have already said it has a length and that the E field has a non zero amplitude ..philosophically can you have it both ways ?

Comment: I don't believe a photon has a width. When approximated as a point particle, it is infinitesimal in all three dimensions, when approximated as a w..  lol from the other side of the universe I could model a 3 decker bus as a point particle, but its not

Comment: upon what you have said up to now, at best its a plane of finite size, if it has a zero amplitude B field, which it cannot

Comment: I just know enough about E&M to say that amplitude of electromagnetic oscilations are definitely not correspondent to spatial width....well unless you can come up with a better explanation of "width", which you cannot, then I am at liberty to claim that is the width, as that term for photons is not defined, until now

Comment: "width" being the min size of a hole an object cannot fit thru, without distortion

Comment: -1 This answer confuses classical fields with quantum mechanical entities.

Comment: @annav no it doesn't as I am talking about mean lengths in a large population

Comment: patently a photon lives in 3D space so saying it has "no width" ie saying it only lives in 2D space or less,  is probably more incorrect than saying it has width ?

Answer (score 1):

The word "photon" is used for the elementary **point** particle that is the gauge boson of the electromagnetic force, one of the three forces in the [standard model of particle physics.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model)

**point** means that as far as our present theory underlying all physics it has no dimensions, it has spin 1, mass zero, and an energy in the energy-momentum four vector describing it of $hν$  where  $ν$ is the frequency of the classical electromagnetic wave that emerges from a large number of photons of that energy. Please see this [answer of mine here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/678092/if-quantum-particles-are-always-waves-then-what-are-we-really-measuring-the-pos/678111#678111) to get an intuition of how single photons leave a footprint compatible of a particle and an accumulations shows the interference of a wave.

There is no length of width for an individual photon assigned by our standard theory at present.

The wave nature of all particles appears in the **probability distribution** and is due to the wavefunction of a given system and its boundary conditions. One particle cannot be a wave.

The Heisenberg uncertainty principle is an envelope of the possible values a measurement of a particle can take, it is wrong to use it as a gauge for a single point particle.

There is no thickness of a single photon, only in accumulation of measurements with the same boundary conditions a concept like thickness , number of photons per volume etc can be ascertained.

Comment: so from measurement of real world phenomena phyisicts worker out the boundary conditions that a wave function would have to meet in order for a given wave function to model reality , so a wave function is a model of reality, not the other way round.   Maxwell's equation say that a photon has a "wavelength" (ie a non zero length) and is made of a B field perpendicular to an E field  , in other words it occupies at least three spatial dimensions?

Comment: if an individual photon cannot exist how come they can do experiments with individual photons ?

Comment: if an individual photon has no thickness, the how come it can interact with a detector, are you saying it is a plane of zero thickness ?

Comment: @TomJones if you read my answer, ofcourse it exists, it is just a point particle as far as our ability to measure and model it in our theories.

Comment: @TomJones  in quantum mechanical interactions there are exchanged virtual particles that model the interaction. One has to study quantum mechanics to speak a bout photons. Otherwise it is the classical E and B electromagnetic wave. It can be shown mathematically to emerge from many photons using quantum field theory

Comment: if a single photon is nothing more than an accumulation of measurements. Then who is doing the measuring ? and how does a collection of measurements interact with a detector  ? ie a tangible entity

Comment: so a photon is energy existing within zero volumes ? ie infinite energy density ?

Comment: @TomJones a single photon is a single photon as seen in the link I gave . see the image here https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHIBN.png . the dots are the single photons

Comment: @TomJones In quantum mechanics there are no such definitions, energy density is a classical physics concept, that can be approximated for collection of particles, not for a single particle

Comment: lol that image, white dots on a black background explains abs nothing , what am I meant to extrapolate from that picture bc the white dots have a width and a height photons must have a width and a height, lol what the hell . Like what is the take home message from that image , if any ?

Comment: so if a single photon has no energy how does it interact with a detector ? If is has no energy how does it change the state of a detector ?

Comment: @ annav are you saying in the model single photons have no energy or in real life they have no energy ?

Comment: Otherwise it is the classical E and B electromagnetic wave. ....so are the Maxwell equations wrong ?

Comment: The Heisenberg uncertainty principle is an envelope of the possible values a measurement of a particle can take, it is wrong to use it as a gauge for a single point particle....so what you are saying here is the lengths of a population of photons  will match some probability density function, say like a gaussian curve for instance, where there will be a mean length which will be very common, but other lengths less common  and very very short or very very long , are rare  ?

Comment: The maxwell equations are correct for the classical EMwave. The single photons have the energy hν it is just assigned to a point particle photon of mass zero. Look you cannot learn quantum mechanics and special relativity in questions and answers, that is what courses are for.

Comment: so if something doesn't exist in your model does that mean it doesn't exist, or  the other way round ?

Comment: I repeat "you cannot learn quantum mechanics and special relativity in questions and answers, that is what courses are for", models exist because they are validated by data, not the other way around ( data exist because of a model, like your naive one ,that models the photon as an increment of the electromagnetic wave. It does not work with the rest of multitudes of data, that show photon particle interactions,)

Comment: Really nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are already excellent, but another way to think about this:  what do we mean by size?  In classical mechanics, one way to think about it is the size determines when a collision or interaction takes place.  For example, if I'm standing 10 feet from the center of a road and 5 foot wide truck goes down the road, there is no collision, but if the truck is 10 feet wide or wider, it hits me (or I jump out of the way to narrowly avoid it!)

We often use this convention in non-classical physics when talking about collisions - i.e. what is the effective cross-sectional area of an atom in a certain type of collision or interaction.

Let's imagine taking this approach for photons in a beam of light.  Based on the [double-slit experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment), the cross sectional area of the photon - the area that describes whether or not there is an interaction (i.e. "from the front") is the width of the beam of light.  Yes, the entire macroscopic width of the beam of light.  If you imagine shining a beam of light on two slits, it creates a diffraction pattern, and the pattern persists even if you dial the intensity down such that only one photon is emitted at a time.  Each individual photon is going through both slits and diffracting with itself!

That then leaves the length of the photon to be calculated, which following a similar logic can be estimated using the classical power of the beam of light and the photon energy.

The key to both of these though is that the effective "size of the particle" is really just a restatement of the physical properties of the macroscopic system, and not intrinsic to the particle itself.  It can be a useful shortcut (sometimes), but it's not really meaningful in a deeper sense.

Comment: Each individual photon is going through both slits and diffracting with itself!....well that is just a guess as realistically nobody has any clue what is going on , some other phenomenon other than interference might be occuring, we just dont know ...its "assumed" to be interference as that is a simple explanation and something we already know ...but equally it could be some other as yet unknown bizarre phenomenon

Comment: we have already agreed the "length"  is one wavelength, not 2, not three , just one , so if a photon has a length of one wavelength and it has an energy of x , then the amplitude of the E ad B fields can be calculated which would be the max extent of its cross sectional area ?

Comment: and we have already agreed there is such a  thing as a single photon

Comment: lets say given a  single photon of energy x and wavelength y the cross sectional area is A  ....if you think the cross sectional area is greater than A, thats fine explain why ?...why would the cross sectional area be some value greater than the max extent of the E field ?

Comment: Im sure we can all agree the max extent of a single photon is not infinite,  therefore it must be some finite amount, greater than 0 but less than infinity

Comment: .its "assumed" to be interference...I mean a photon is utterly utterly stupid, if a photon is approaching a single slit or a double slit , of just the right spacing, how does the photon know there is a double slit there. It has no eyes , how is it even aware of the other slit ...interference raises more questions than it answers

Comment: the double slit experiment almost endows photons with some form of intelligence

Comment: one explanation is the double slits are projecting some sort of field out into space which communicate to the incoming photon that there is a double slit , of just the right spacing, ahead of the photon ?

Comment: No one agreed to anything you've written here.

Comment: lol dude obv you havent read the other comments ....if you cannot be bothered to read all the comments, then dont talk like you know what yr talkin about

Comment: I stopped reading when you wrote we have agreed on the length of the photon as one wavelength.  I can't be bothered to read when someone is making statements that are completely false, why would I waste my time?

Comment: I stopped reading when you wrote we have agr...mmm ok seems like you know much more than the rest of us...if yr such a genius what is the length of a photon ?